# How to handle the exception in OpenFire Restapi in php?

Tags: php, exception, openfire

Currently I installed openfire in my server and started to use it. I tried to create a user in openfire using Restapi . And I got output as I expected.

Now i tried to create a user with the username "abcdef" which is already existed.  I want a message that says "username already exists" but instead I get an exception.

The exception:

```
Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error response [url] http://myip:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users [status code] 409 [reason phrase] Conflict' in /var/www/html/open_fire_internal/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:88
```

The message from the exception:

> Client error response [url] http://myip:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users [status code] 409 [reason phrase] Conflict

Stack trace:

```
#0 [...]/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Subscriber/HttpError.php(33): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Message\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Message\Response))
#1 [...]/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Event/Emitter.php(109): GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\HttpError->onComplete(Object(GuzzleHttp\Event\CompleteEvent), 'complete')
#2 [...]/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RequestFsm.php(91): GuzzleHttp\Event\Emitter->emit('complete', Object(GuzzleHttp\Event\CompleteEvent))
#3 [...]/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RequestFsm.php(132): GuzzleHttp\RequestFsm->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Transaction))in /var/www/html/open_fire_internal/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 88
```

So can anyone help me to overcome from this issue?

Comment: Can you show your code!

Comment: `include "../vendor/autoload.php";`
`// Create the Openfire Rest api object`
`$api = new Gidkom\OpenFireRestApi\OpenFireRestApi;`
`// Add a new user to OpenFire and add to a group`
`$result = $api->addUser('kandan', 'mani');`
`// Check result if command is succesful`
`if($result['status']) {`
    `// Display result, and check if it's an error or correct response`
    `echo 'Success: ';`
    `echo $result['message'];`
`} else {`
    `// Something went wrong, probably connection issues`
    `echo 'Error: ';`
    `echo $result['message'];`
`}`

Comment: when the username doens't exist in openfire i get success message but when the username exists in openfire i get that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check whether the user is exists or not than add them

```
$user = $api->getuser($username);

if(!$user)
{
$result = $api->addUser('Username', 'Password', 'Real Name', 'email@email.tld', array('Group 1'));

// Check result if command is succesful
if($result) {
    // Display result, and check if it's an error or correct response
    echo ($result['result']) ? 'Success: ' : 'Error: ';
    echo $result['message'];
} else {
    // Something went wrong, probably connection issues
}
}
else
{

echo 'user already exists';
}
```